# Strange Symbol on center of screen using PyGame with DirectFB

Tags: pygame, raspberry-pi, directfb

I am using pygame to draw a GUI on tiny SPI LCD mount as `/dev/fb1` via directfb.

Whatever I draw, there is a strange symbol display in center of screen.
[image: pi logo with strange symbol]

[image: green lines with strange symbol]

[image: mark of symbol]

If I run df_matrix, the strange symbol does not appear.

[image: df_matrix without symbal]

If I draw in pygame, then manually open `/dev/fb1`, write screen data, the strange symbol does not appear.

[image: manual draw to fb without symbol]

So, how to get rid of this annoying symbol?

Comment: My first thought is that it's somehow a mouse cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To isolate the problem, I have tried many solutions,
upgrade pygame from 1.9.6 to 2.0.0.dev12, invalid.
upgrade sdl1 to sdl2, invalid.
recompile and install directfb 1.7.7, invalid.
invoke pygame.mouse.set_visible(False), invalid.
export SDL_NOMOUSE=1, invalid.

finally, as Kingsley and Cribber suggested, it must be  a mouse cursor, so I dig out the right solution:

```
add no-cursor to /etc/directfbrc
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is truly the mouse cursor as Kingsley suggested in the comments, you can disable the cursor in pygame with:

```
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: I have set that property already before run each test. In addition, os.environ['SDL_NOMOUSE'] = '1'

Comment: maybe it is the mouse cursor, and here https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/mouse-set-visible-directfb-fails/9708  someone said pygame + sdl + directfb, the mouse cursor can't be hidden, but I don't know how to execute that code within python.

Comment: to be honest pygame is my jam but I don't know enough about sdl / directfb to help you with the problem in the link.